# Macros to automatically consolidate data

Tags: excel, vba

What the best way to automatically consolidate two columns (name and quantity) into two new ones where data is grouped by name and sum for each grouped is computed. I managed to do this with a pivotal table but i need to be able to refresh the data each time there is new update or addition to the orignal columns.

Thx

Comment: will this be going into an xlsm file? i.e. do you already have some vba in the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a named range with an `offset` function and then populated the pivot table based on that named range this will solve your problem:

1. Create your named range, **"myData"** and use the following formula:

   ```
   =OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A),COUNTA(Sheet1!$1:$1))`
   ```
2. Create your pivot with **"myData"** as the range:

   [image: Pivot example]